# jqGrid in IE 9: How to enable scrolling after key is released

Tags: jqgrid, internet-explorer-9

jqGrid is used in virtual scrolling mode. If <kbd>Page Down</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> is hold down for some time, released, and pressed again, scrolling in Internet Explorer 9 does not work anymore. After key is released, jqGrid loses focus.

To continue scrolling, jqGrid needs clicked again.

How to keep focus in jqGrid after key is released in IE 9 ?

In FireFox focus remains in jqGrid as expected.

```
grid.jqGrid({
   scroll: 1,
   datatype: "json",
   mtype: 'POST',
   autoencode: true,
   gridview: true,
   pager: '#pager',
   viewrecords: true,
...
```